# Blank for new columns for old rows dynamodb

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using c#.

I have thousands of rows in dynamodb like

[image: Old Rows]

Now I insert few more rows but with different columns

like

[image: Row 3 and Row4 are new rows]

Here Row 3 and Row 4 are new rows

Now I need structure like below

[image: Rows with default value]

Now I want old rows should have default 0 or blank string for new columns,

I don't want to iterate through old rows and updated items.

Is there any way to set default values..

Comment: Are you doing this for display purpose or you want to store "0" in tables?

Comment: You didn't make it clear why it is useful to have this, especially because you confirmed you see it doesn't fit with NoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve doesn't really work with NoSQL type databases. Technically, there is no concept of rows and columns when it comes to DynamoDB. Instead, there are items (your records) that contain any number of attributes. You can read more about it [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.TablesItemsAttributes).

If you're using an object mapper, I'd recommend dealing with this logic on that level, ie. when getting items from DynamoDB you can assign default values there if there is a need to do so.

Comment: Yes I know this against the NoSql concept, and also as I think by implementing this concept we lose the benefits of nosql, but someone asked me for this, that's why I put here is it possible..

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be archived with a DynamoDB query. DynamoDB only "knows" about indexed keys (partition key, sort key and secondary indices) and is not able to tell you the name of all properties that exist in your table (unlike a relational database).

The only thing I can think of is:

- Scan the entire database
- Store all property names in e.g. a [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)
- For each item: Add the missing properties, assing your default values  and update it